# Are Python libraries os specific

Tags: python

Why does some Python libraries fail to install on different Operating System. If I compare it with Java, python has wheel and egg (which is discarded), and once I have jar, I can run it on any System irrespective of OS but in case of Python there are some libraries which are clearly mentioned to be supported on some specific OS. Python too has a byte code but why is it OS specific( Tensorflow is supported on Ubuntu but when I try to install it on cnetos I get errors), isn't it supposed to work like Java wherein i can just download the binaries and simply execute the code.
Also when I do pip install some libraries is it compiling the source code. I know there are various implementation of Python (CPython, JPython etc)

I have read the articles around Python from various links and the one I found useful is http://www.techdarting.com/2014/04/python-compiled-or-interpreted-language.html

Comment: The Ubuntu/CentOS issue is almost certainly a packaging problem, not anything inherent to Python.

Comment: @chepner I think it's mostly because of native libraries which are compiled on specific os

Comment: I guess some of these libraries make faulty assumptions (e.g. where some refs are stored, or named, etc) when things go sideways.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of libraries, for both languages: the ones written in Python (or Java), and the ones that link against native code (with [native extensions](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html) for Python, or [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) in Java). The native ones might have requirements that cannot be satisfied in certain environments. It is just that you have run into many more native libraries for Python than for Java. Usually native code is used either to access non-standard hardware (obviously platform-dependent) that is not available from the bytecode (that is designed as platform-independent), or because native code is faster than bytecode. Python being rather slower than Java is one of the reasons native libraries are more common in the Python world than in the Java world. (E.g. one common piece of Java code that is platform-dependent is Eclipse; one reason is that it uses native graphical libraries rather than Java's.)